# Rails 4 nested form not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have scoured all the other questions relating to this topic here, but I am still having this problem.  I have a nested form inside a nested form.  Answer choices are inside questions which are inside survey.  I had no problem setting up the questions, and they save fine.  The Answer choices, though, are not saving, and I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

survey.rb

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :forms, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answer_choices, through: :question

  validates :name, uniqueness: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['text'].blank?},
  allow_destroy: true
end
```

question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :responses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answer_choices, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer_choices, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['content'].blank?},
  allow_destroy: true

end
```

answer_choice.rb

```
class AnswerChoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

survey_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new(author_id: session[:user_id])
    @survey.questions.build
    @survey.questions.each { |question| 4.times { question.answer_choices.build }}
  end

  def edit
    @survey.questions.build
    @survey.questions.each { |question| 4.times { question.answer_choices.build }}
  end

def survey_params
  params.require(:survey).permit(:name, :description, :author_id,
      questions_attributes: [:id, :text, :required, :response_type,
      :_destroy, :number])
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
  <% if @survey.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@survey.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this survey from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @survey.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :author_id %>
  </div>

  <h2>Questions</h2>
  <%= f.fields_for(:questions) do |ff| %>
    <%= render 'questions', :f => ff %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Submit Question'%>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= link_to 'Finish Survey', surveys_path %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

_questions.html.erb

```
<div>
  <span><%= f.index + 1 %>. </span>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :number, value: f.index + 1 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :text, "Question" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :text %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :response_type %><br>
    <%= f.select :response_type, [["Yes/No", "yes/no"], ["Short Answer", "string"], ["Long Answer", "text"], ["Multiple Choice", "multi"]] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :required %>
    <%= f.check_box :required %>
  </div>
<div>
  <p>Answer Choices</p>
  <%= f.fields_for(:answer_choices) do |ff| %>
    <%= render 'answer_choices', :f => ff %>
  <% end %>
</div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :_destroy %>
    <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  </div>
</div>
```

_answer_choices.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :content %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :_destroy %>
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few changes in your code.

Change your `new` method like this

```
def new
    @survey = Survey.new(author_id: session[:user_id])
    @questions = @survey.questions.build
    @answer_choices = 4.times { @questions.answer_choices.build }
  end
```

Your `survey_params` should look like this

```
def survey_params
  params.require(:survey).permit(:name, :description, :author_id,
      questions_attributes: [:id, :text, :required, :response_type,
      :_destroy, :number, answer_choices_attributes: [:id,:content,:_destroy]])
end
```

And in your `form` code, change these lines

```
<%= f.fields_for(:questions) do |ff| %>
<%= f.fields_for(:answer_choices) do |ff| %>
```

into

```
<%= f.fields_for @questions do |ff| %>
<%= f.fields_for @answer_choices do |ff| %>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I made the first two changes, but if I made the change you recommend in the form code, it broke.  It worked great with just the first two, though.